# Can I improve multiple answers of mine at one time?

Tags: discussion, answers

In the beginning , when I joined Hinduism Stack Exchange, I have given some answers to questions with word directly copied from source material.

**But now I want to reformat
some of those answers with my own wordings. Simply I want to re-write those answers in my own words, without changing meaning. Like Spelling corrections , grammatical corrections , adding passages etc. So can I improve multiple answers at a time.
Is it allowed to do so?**

Comment: Yes, feel free to edit your answers in any way you see fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have given some answers to questions with word directly copied from source material.

Following pages may help you for your above mentioned issue:

- [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [How to reference material written by others](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)
- [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/260388)

> So can I improve multiple answers at a time. Is it allowed to do so?

**Yes, you can always edit/revise your posts with the help of edit button. Improving posts are encouraged as it enriches the quality of the site!** (visit some [badges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/badges) awarded on the basis of edits)

There is no problem with editing multiple posts at a time but you may face some [rate-limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/260388) restrictions for editing, based on your privileges and site design.

Comment: Thanks , your answer is useful.